# Retrieve the list of friends of specific user when i select that user in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I had two entities User and friends in app engine JDO in which the user had a list of friends so i want when i select from table User also retrieve from the entity friend the list of friends associated only to that user....how can i perform this in app engine ?

Comment: What does your data model look like?

Comment: It is simple only user that supposed to have a set of friends so i need in the entity User List<Friends> I'm new in app engine so I don't know how to manage this relation..how when i select the user I can retrieve all his friends from table Friends

Answer (score 0):

Relation between entities for python are described here (I guess this is pretty much the same for Java): http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html

It seems that you need a many to many relation. The simplest way to do this is to have a list of db.key property in your user model. You can make sure that whenever you create a new connection between friends, both lists of friends are updated.

Alternatively you could define a function that searches the db for users that have a certain user's key in their friends list, using a gql query. However IMHO this seems somewhat less organised than the other method.